# Primes separated by multiples of 4

Tags: prime-numbers

> ***Q***. Is it the case that for every prime $p$, there is a larger prime $q$ such
>   that $q = p + 4 n$, $n \ge 2$ ?

For example: $5 + 8 = 13$, $13 + 16 = 29$, $29 + 8 = 37$, and so on.

I came upon this constructing a stacked version of Ulam's spiral,
arranging that the front-right corner cell of every layer is prime.
Continuing this indefinitely requires a positive answer to the posed question.

---

[image: Stacked5]

---

[image: Layer29]

          

<sup>3rd layer, starting with $14$, following $13$ from 2nd layer.</sup>

---

Comment: Cf. [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), but it's not true for $p=2$

Comment: Well, assuming $p$ is odd, Dirichlet tells us that there are infinitely many primes $\equiv  p \pmod 4$, so sure.  For $4$, of course, there are easier proofs available.  Or were you asking something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many as long as $p \neq 2.$  This is a consequence of [Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).  Any arithmetic progression of the form $a+nd$ contains an infinite number of primes as long as $a$ and $d$ are coprime.  In your case, as long as $p \neq 2,$ it is coprime to $4$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the full machinery of Dirichlet's Theorem.  You can prove that there are infinitely many $4n+1$ primes and infinitely many $4n-1$ primes via a method similar to Euclid's proof that all primes are infinite in number.

Suppose there were only finitely many $4n-1$ primes.  Let $\Pi$ be the product of all of them and define $M=2\Pi+1$.  Then $M$ is one less than a multiple of $4$ and so must have a $4n-1$ prime factor, but no such factor can be among the primes used to form the product $\Pi$.  Therefore there must always be more $4n-1$ primes than those included in any finite list.

The argument for $4n+1$ primes is similar except the polynomial used there is $M=\Pi^2+1$.  Here you need some additional theory from modular arithmetic, notably the fact that $-1$ cannot be congruent to any square modulo a $4n-1$ prime.

Comment: Good point; +$1$

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), if $\gcd(4,p)=1$ (i.e., $p\ne2$), there are in fact infinitely many primes of the form $p+4n$.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}$